# jQuery load with php $_GET didn't work

Tags: php, jquery

i want to send Get  when the link clicked to receive the result in php code
and this what happened
this in php file  working perfect

```html
        <html>
    <a class="cc" href="#">click me</a>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
    
            $(".cc").click(function () {
                $(".body").load('page.php ')
            })});
    
    </script>
    
    <section class="body"></section>
    
    </html>
```

but when i put GET to the href didn't work just Flashing content

```html
<html>
    <a class="cc" href="?id=1">click me</a>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
    
            $(".cc").click(function () {
                $(".body").load('page.php ')
            })});
    
    </script>
    
    <section class="body"></section>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you need to have the `$_GET['id']` in your `page.php` as well to use for the returned content? If so, in addition to Praveen's answer, you need to add the `id=1` to the `.load('page.php')`.... like `.load('page.php?id=1')` or `.load('page.php'+$(this).attr('href'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, you really need to stop the `<a>` from following the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".body").load('page.php');
  });
});
```